# How can I print the subject and body of a GMail email using the python API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api

```
    results = service.users().messages().list(
        userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX'], maxResults=1).execute()
    labels = results.get('messages', [])
    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['id'])
```

This script prints the message Id of the most recent email. How can I print the subject and body of the emails? I can't find any documentation on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

**1. To make your coide less confusing it is recommended to call your messages as such rather than as labels:**

```py
    results = service.users().messages().list(
        userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX'], maxResults=1).execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])
    if not messages:
        print('No messages found.')
    else:
        print('Messages:')
        for message in messages:
            print(message['id'])
```

**2. Have a look at the [message resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message):**

```
{
  "id": string,
  "threadId": string,
  "labelIds": [
    string
  ],
  "snippet": string,
  "historyId": string,
  "internalDate": string,
  "payload": {
    object (MessagePart)
  },
  "sizeEstimate": integer,
  "raw": string
}
```

`payload` includes the object [MessagePart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#messagepart), that contains the following nested objects:

```
{
  "partId": string,
  "mimeType": string,
  "filename": string,
  "headers": [
    {
      object (Header)
    }
  ],
  "body": {
    object (MessagePartBody)
  },
  "parts": [
    {
      object (MessagePart)
    }
  ]
}
```

This resource allows to access both `body`, as well as `subject` - the latter is contained in the message [headers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#header):

```
{
  "name": string,
  "value": string
}
```

However, those objects are not being returned with [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list), but only with [users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get)

Sample:

```py
    results = service.users().messages().list(
        userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX'], maxResults=1).execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])
    if not messages:
        print('No messages found.')
    else:
        print('Messages:')
        for message in messages:
            print(message['id'])
            messageResource = service.users().messages().get(userId="me",id=message['id']).execute()
            headers=messageResource["payload"]["headers"]
            subject= [j['value'] for j in headers if j["name"]=="Subject"]
            print(subject)
```