# How can I get the subject of an email gmail python API

Tags: python-3.x, google-apps-script, gmail, python-3.9

```
def getbodyinbox():
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    label_name = "READ-BY-SCRIPT"
    label_id = 'Label_8507504117657095973'
    results = service.users().messages().list(
        userId='me', q="-label:"+label_name, maxResults=1).execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])
    body = []
    if not messages:
        body = "no messages"
        return body
    else:
        for message in messages:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(
                userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
            labels = msg['labelIds']
            if "INBOX" in labels:
                headers = msg['payload']['headers']
                headers = str(headers)
                print(headers)
                if "class_ix" in headers:
                    body.append(msg['payload']['parts'])
                    if 'data' in body[0][0]['body']:
                        body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
                            body[0][0]['body']['data'])
                    elif 'data' in body[0][1]['body']:
                        body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
                            body[0][1]['body']['data'])
                    body = str(body)

                        
                    return body


print(getbodyinbox())
```

This is my code so far with the part that gets the credentials and all of the imports removed. It gets the body of the most recent email without a label 'READ-BY-SCRIPT' that also has the label INBOX. How can I get the subject of the email instead of the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Have a look at the [message resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#resource), [MessagePart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message.MessagePart) and [header](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#header)

The structure is the following:

```
  "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
```

and:

[image]

So, in other words, the subject is contained in the headers.

You can retrieve in Python with

```py
headers = msg['payload']['headers']
subject= [i['value'] for i in headers if i["name"]=="Subject"]
```

Comment: It outputs this error:


```  File "/Users/me/Coding/Gmail/getBodyInbox.py", line 77, in <module>
    print(getbodyinbox())
  File "/Users/mel/Coding/Gmail/getBodyInbox.py", line 62, in getbodyinbox
    subject= [i['value'] for i in headers if i["name"]=="Subject"]
  File "/Users/mel/Coding/Gmail/getBodyInbox.py", line 62, in <listcomp>
    subject= [i['value'] for i in headers if i["name"]=="Subject"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Can you show how you integrated it into the rest of your code? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459679/how-can-i-print-the-subject-and-body-of-a-gmail-email-using-the-python-api) for a more complete sample.

Comment: I ran the code again and it just fixed itself? It seems fine now.